# Laravel routes not working properly

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5.3

In Laravel, If I call a url from controller it didn't work properly.
For example I am in this location like `example.com/dev/lar/public/index.php/location/{$id}`. Now I am redirection to following routes `location/create` . For example url will be `<a href="location/create"></a>` . Then url shows `example.com/dev/lar/public/index.php/location/location/create`.

My web file is given below.

```
Route::get("location/all","LocationController@showall");
Route::resource("location","LocationController");
```

Update :  I updated my error message in screenshot
Error message screenshot is given below.

[img]https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnKUO.png

Comment: Is it possible to provide the error messages that you are getting? That will help to determine whether it is a .htaccess issue, controller issue or view issue.

Comment: Can you lead the link with / so it should look like <a href="/location/create"></a>

Comment: @Extrakun I updated my question with error message which is showing in screenshot

Comment: No it is not possible leading the link with / but I am not using a single domain for this application. It is located under sub folder of a domain. @LeaTano

Comment: The error means there is not route for the request. Can you please run php artisan route:list.  Can you also create the link using URL::to('location/create')

Comment: I know this not route list. My route will be like example.com/dev/lar/public/index.php/location/create but using href route shows example.com/dev/lar/public/index.php/location/location/create . That's my question.

Comment: @Vam Will you please tell what echo url(); return in your view? if it return base url of your project then you can bind this result in href attribute.

Comment: @B.Desai Here is view url by using url()->current() functions  example.com/dev/lar/public/index.php/location/create

Comment: Using URL::to(location/create) it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just use URL::to('location/create') function. Then route works. This solution was suggested by @lea Tanao